# Eliminating duplicate results when querying a family tree with core.logic

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm modeling a family tree with core.logic. I would like to `run*` the queries and have them return all the results *without duplication*. Replacing all `defn` with `def tabled` gives me the results I expect (for now at least), and I know that `condu` and `onceo` can reduce the number of results, but I'm not sure if either of those are the best way to eliminate duplicates.

I'm particularly worried about my current approach because it seems like duplicate work to declare both the relations and the functions. I know that some of my relations are 'mutually recursive' (`mothero` and `womano` reference each other), but I did this because in the future I might add a new `(defrel mother*)`, which should allow it to infer that a mother is both a parent and a woman.

```
(defrel man* person)
(defrel woman* person)
(defrel parent* child father)

(fact man* :Father)
(fact woman* :Mother)
(fact man* :Son)
(fact woman* :Daughter)
(fact parent* :Son :Father)
(fact parent* :Son :Mother)
(fact parent* :Daughter :Father)
(fact parent* :Daughter :Mother)

(defn mano [person]
(conde 
    [(man* person)]
    [(fresh [c]
        (fathero c person))]))

(defn womano [person]
(conde
    [(woman* person)]
    [(fresh [c]
        (mothero c person))]))

(defn parento [child person]
(conde
    [(parent* child person)]
    [(mothero child person)]
    [(fathero child person)]))

(defn fathero [child father]
(all
    (mano father)
    (parento child father)))

(defn mothero [child mother]
(all 
    (womano mother)
    (parento child mother)))

(defn siblingso [c1 c2 mother father]
    (all
        (mothero c1 mother)
        (mothero c2 mother)
        (fathero c1 father)
        (fathero c2 father)
        (!= c1 c2)))

(run 10 [q]
    (fresh [child parent]
        (parento child parent)
        (== q [child parent])))

(run 10 [q]
    (fresh [c1 c2 p1 p2]
        (siblingso c1 c2 p1 p2)
        (== q [c1 c2 p1 p2])))
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but the goals (stuff ending in 'o') seems (as you said) redundant and they are. Also, you can't get `parento` to run with `run*` because there are no constraints on your queries. It will try to return an infinite list of child-parent pairs. Here are some example queries using your relations:

```
;; find all child-parent pairs
(run* [q] (fresh [c p] (parent* c p) (== q [c p])))
;=> ([:Daughter :Mother] [:Son :Mother] [:Daughter :Father] [:Son :Father])

;; find all child-father pairs
(run* [q] (fresh [c p] (parent* c p) (man* p) (== q [c p])))
;=> ([:Daughter :Father] [:Son :Father])

;; find all daughter-father pairs
(run* [q] (fresh [c p] (parent* c p) (man* p) (woman* c) (== q [c p])))
;=> ([:Daughter :Father])

;; some new facts
(fact parent* :grand-child :Son)
(fact parent* :great-grand-child :grand-child)

;; find all people who are grandparent
(run* [q] (fresh [c p gp] (parent* c p) (parent* p gp) (== q [gp])))
;=> ([:Mother] [:Father] [:Son])
```

And you can go on like that for a while. Logic programming makes a very powerful query language on its own even when used only with simple relations.

**Update**: Here's an example of `brothero` where the second argument should be the brother:

```
(defn brothero [a b]
  (fresh [f]
    (!= a b)
    (parent* a f)
    (parent* b f)
    (man* f)
    (man* b))))

(run* [q] (fresh [a b] (brothero a b) (== q [a b])))
;=> ([:Daughter :Son])
```

As you see I don't bother to define a `parento` goal as it is redundant. You should note that `(!= a b)` is required to not get pairs containing the same person twice and that there's a constraint on the parent to prevent doubling the answers. Obviously this example wouldn't work if you don't have the father recorded or for a man that has children from multiple women.

Comment: The reason I've defined the functions parento, fathero, siblingso, etc. is that I then want to use them as building blocks for defining larger relations. Like cousinso would be easier to define using siblingso and parento. instead of restricting it to just parent*. I'd like to end up build functions for any type of relation, brothers, uncles, 2nd cousin, ancestors, descendants, related, etc. I just don't know how to define these so that they would be accepting of new relations like sister* while also terminating when run with run*.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of (simplified version) of `brothero`, hope this will help you achieve your goals! ;-)

Comment: I've made another small change in the last example, as there was no need to use `defne` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursive relation, you can use this extension
 https://github.com/niitsuma/Racket-miniKanren/tree/recursive

Maybe rewriting

walk walk* unify occurs-check

like this extension, 
also enables recursive relation in clojure